# adding something like showcase view master lib of android to my website

Tags: jquery, showcaseview

I just checked the Google docs and saw something like the [showcase view master library](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) in android that helps the user to understand what is going on in the screen. 
For example introducing new features added to the web site and new buttons and introducing new changes and places of the page etc). 
Can anybody tell me the name of the jQuery or whatever it is to do the same in my web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an official port of this library for jQuery/Javascript because, being a distinctly "Android" element, I didn't think it was appropriate. However, if you look at the [GitHub page](http://espiandev.github.io/ShowcaseView/) there is a very basic implementation which "showcases" the title. The key jQuery is:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
        var left = $('#viewTarget').offset().left - 300 + $('#viewTarget').width() / 2;
        var top = $('#viewTarget').offset().top - 300 + $('#viewTarget').height() / 2;
        $('#showcaseview').offset({top: top, left: left});
    });
```

Where `viewTarget` is being showcased. This doesn't however take into account scrolling, and probably has other issues. Unfortunately, I'm not a web developer!